# Portable shebang line

Tags: unix, scripting, shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

This is the shebang line to a lot of scripts I'm writing lately.

Hard coding the path of the binary seems like it could create some problems. For instance, if one of my users has Perl installed at /something_else/bin then they'd have to change all the shebangs.

I've seen some tools that will automatically replace the shebangs, but I'm wondering if there is something simpler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`env(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Comment: what is /usr/bin/env is somewhere else on their system?

Comment: Then it most likely will be there *as well as* in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: You *could* maybe just use "#!env perl" of "#!perl" and rely on the path being set (But I don't like it).

Comment: @Brenton, sorry $PATH is not parsed by #!.

Comment: Ah, true... knew there had to be a reason I hadn't ever seen it done :)

Comment: Works for plain `#!/usr/bin/perl`, but if you need to pass an option to perl (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env perl -lp`) it will fail on many systems because the kernel can only handle up to one argument.  This is in line with the UNIX motto: *Why Solve the Problem Properly?*

Comment: Related information: [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash)

Answer (score 1):

For odd embedded systems where env is not in /usr/bin/env (E.g. NAS boxes running funplug etc) this might work. Based on the  [ActivePerl / DOS trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062772/can-perl-and-batch-run-in-the-same-batch-file)

```
#!/bin/sh
exec perl -x -S "$0" "$@"
#!perl
print "hello";
```