# Can Perl and Batch run in the same batch file?

Tags: perl, batch-file, polyglot

I've got a batch script that does some processing and calls some perl scripts.

My question is if there was a way to put the perl code directly into the batch script and have it run both types of scripts.

Answer (score 26):

[Active Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) has been doing this for years!

Below is a skeleton. You can only call perl *once* though. Because passing it the [`-x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-x%2A) switch says that you'll find the perl code *embedded* in this file, and perl reads down the file until it finds a perl shebang (`#!...perl`) and starts executing there. Perl will ignore everything past the `__END__` and because you told DOS to `goto endofperl` it won't bother with anything until it gets to the label.

```
@rem = '--*-Perl-*--
@echo off
perl -x -S %0 %*
goto endofperl


@rem -- BEGIN PERL -- ';
#!d:/Perl/bin/perl.exe -w
#line 10

use strict; 


__END__
:endofperl
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!  I would vote on this but it's telling me to register to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

In fact this is exactly what the `pl2bat` tool does: it transforms a perl program into a batch file which embeds the perl program. Have a look to pl2bat.bat itself.

So you can take the `.pl`, convert it with `pl2bat`, and then tweak the batch part as you need. The biggest part of the batch code must be put at the end of the file (near the `:end_of_perl` label) because in the code at the top you are limited to not using single quotes.

However:

- this simple approach will not work if you need to embed more that one perl file
- this will be a maintenance nightmare.

So I suggest instead to write the whole process in one Perl program.

**Update:** if you have one script and some Perl modules that you want to combine in a single batch file, you can combine the Perl file using [`fatpack`](https://metacpan.org/module/App::FatPacker), and then apply `pl2bat` on the result.

Comment: That was the problem.  I had 2 perl files that I wanted to use.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way to do this, but it wont be pretty.  You can echo your perl code into a temp `.pl` file and then run that file from within your `.bat`.

Comment: Thought about that but thought it would make my work buddy cry.  :)