# Using a non-system-dependent bash shebang (instead of #!/bin/bash) that works everywhere?

Tags: bash, shell, path, environment-variables, shebang

I typically put a shebang for bash at the top of my shell scripts, e.g.:

`#!/usr/bin/bash`

However I see many other variants of this, like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` etc.

It seems to me these different conventions would result in compatibility or portability issues. If my bash is at another location than someone else's, my script won't work on their machine and vice versa.

If a shell interpreter like bash is apparently not always at the same location, isn't it plain WRONG to explicitly use a hardcoded path in a script?

I understood you can use a somewhat more flexible or less system-dependent approach like this:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Which results in the (or a?) local version of bash, wherever that may be installed.

Does the latter variant always work? Or is there a better approach that has the highest chance of referring to any system's bash regardless of where it's installed?

Comment: This might help: [What is the difference between “#!/usr/bin/env bash” and “#!/usr/bin/bash”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16365130/3776858) or [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21612980/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I see, thanks. Is `/usr/bin/env` "guaranteed" to exist? Or at least, more so than `/usr/bin/bash` ? Otherwise it would still suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Just go with #!/usr/bin/env bash . Screwed up systems lose out, but you tried your best, and you're not in the business of unscrewing them anyway.

Comment: @Roadowl Unfortunately, using `env` makes the script dependent not only on the system, but on the environment (specifically, the `PATH`) the process gets started with. So the exact same script on the same computer may run under different interpreters depending on how it's launched.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either "#!/bin/bash" or "#!/usr/bin/bash".  On a modern Linux distro, `bash` should be installed in both places.

Apparently, that isn't true for OpenBSD ... which uses `ksh` as the default shell.  But on an OpenBSD system, you are liable to find that `bash` isn't installed at all.  It is apparently an optional package, and the admin may have not installed it.

So, if you want to *maximize* portability, use "/bin/sh" and restrict yourself to standard POSIX shell syntax and commands.  "/bin/sh" is typically a link to `bash` or `ksh`, and runs in POSIX compliant mode.

---

Other variations:

- "#!/usr/local/bin/bash" typically won't work on Linux.  If it does, it may give you a locally built / modified version of `bash`.
- "#!/usr/bin/env bash" should work, with a couple of caveats:

  1. This will give you whatever version of `bash` is first on the user's command search path (i.e. `$PATH`).
  2. It is conceivable that the path to `env` may be different, or that it may not exist.  (The `env` command wasn't in the first version of the POSIX specs.)