# What does a shebang line useable with conda look like?

Tags: conda

I run python 3, mostly under linux but shall work with windows also.

Without conda, the shebang line is

```
   #! /usr/bin/python3
```

giving the location of the python interpreter. 
But what if i use conda??? Then the interpreter depends on the environment.... 
But how can i manage that my script runs in any environment??

There seems to be a variable in conda, `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` holding the environment. 
If i have activated sth but base the interpreter is e.g. in

```
/home/ernst/.conda/envs/$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV/bin/python
```

but for base it is just `/opt/conda/bin/python` on linux. 
Well how to get all this under a hood also platform transparent??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` -- in which case it'll use whichever python it'll find in the path first. So, if your default python is conda - then that's what'll be executing this script.

[Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash)